# Javascript - How to call a method in another method within the same class

Tags: javascript

How can I call a method in another method within the same class in javascript. I have tried calling it

```
this.save(books);
```

like so. but I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.save is not a function

Any Suggestions

```
class Book {
  constructor(title, author, isbn) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.isbn = isbn;
  }

  static getBooks() {
    const books = localStorage.getItem('books');
    return books === null ? [] : JSON.parse(books);
  }

  static displayBooks() {
    const books = Book.getBooks();
    books.forEach((book) => {
      const ui = new UI();
      ui.addBookToList(book);
    });
  }

  static addBook(book) {
    console.log(this);
    const books = Book.getBooks();
    books.push(book);
    this.save(books);
  }

  static removeBook(isbn) {
    const books = Book.getBooks(),
      bookIndex = books.findIndex((book) => book.isbn === isbn);
    books.splice(bookIndex, 1);
    this.save(books);
  }

  save(books) {
    localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(books));
  }
}
```

Comment: your other methods are static.

Comment: You can't access an instance method from a static method (unless you pass it an instance). Are you sure `addBook` is supposed to be static, or `save` isn't?

Comment: Why are some of these methods static when they reference “this”? I thought static meant they don’t need an instance to work?

Comment: Your class mixes multiple concepts. Is it a book (as the name and the constructor suggest) or a collection of books (as the methods suggest)? Split the behaviours into separate classes (one for a book, one for a collection of books). Do not use `static` methods, you don't need them (nobody needs `static` methods, they are just global functions with fancy names).

Comment: @axiac Thanks for pointing out! I have moved all the static methods to a new `class Store` and using the book class to only create books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods are called on class itself and not an instance of the class either make `save` method static or make `caller` method non static.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static